# Accessing $scope inside template of directive on $routeChangeSuccess

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, scope, directive

currently i'm trying to write a breadcrumb for learning purposes in angular :) I'm waiting for the $routeChangeSuccess event and populate an array with the name crumb. This array is read with ng-repeat in the template for the breadcrumb. I also want to have access to a variable of the scope. Examples:

```
app.directive('breadCrumb', ['$location', '$route', '$routeParams', function(location, route, routeParams) {
    return {
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
             $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(next, current) { 
                  var loc = location.path();
                  if(loc.indexOf('/users') >-1 && loc!='/users') 
                      $scope.crumb= [{href:"/users",val:"Meine Kommilitonen"}, 
                        {href:"/users/"+current.params.id,val: current.params.id}];
             });
         },
         template: '<div ng-bind="test"></div><div style="float:left" ng-repeat="item in crumb"><a href="{{item.href}}">{{item.val}}</a></div><div style="clear:both"></div>'
    }
}])
```

this works just fine. But now i want to push a object like {href: current.params.id, val: $scope.user.userName} This value is in the controller, which loads the template for the route. if i write this like {{$route.current.scope.users.userName}} directly in the template its fine.

Now how can i push this value to the array, so that it is bind to the div and will be interpreted as a value of the controller. Hopefully you can understand my issue.

EDIT: I've searched for a long time now. My need is (i know that nothing else works for my purpose) that i need to compile s.th like this: '{{route.current.scope.user.userName}}' inside the directive in the linkfunction.

Comment: share fiddle or plunker so that you get faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a value in your controller and you want it available in the directive?

This can be accessed via attributes (attrs) or two way data binding (scope). I will show the two-way binding example.

JS (directive):

```
app.directive('breadCrumb', ['$location', '$route', '$routeParams', function(location, route, routeParams) {
    return {
        // add scope
        scope: {
            myValue: "=" // = means two way binding (you could probably use @ for one way binding)
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             console.log(scope.myValue); // the value on the directive
             // yourArray.push(scope.myValue);

             scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(next, current) { 
                  var loc = location.path();
                  if(loc.indexOf('/users') >-1 && loc!='/users') 
                      scope.crumb= [{href:"/users",val:"Meine Kommilitonen"}, 
                        {href:"/users/"+current.params.id,val: current.params.id}];
             });
         },
         template: '<div ng-bind="test"></div><div style="float:left" ng-repeat="item in crumb"><a href="{{item.href}}">{{item.val}}</a></div><div style="clear:both"></div>'
    }
}])
```

JS (controller):

```
$scope.someValue = {
    href: "/users",
    val: 1 
};
```

HTML:

```
<div bread-crumb my-value="someValue" ></div>
```

Another way to do this is using attrs, not needing scope, the HTML is the same

```
<div bread-crumb my-value="someValue" ></div>
```

JS :

```
app.directive('breadCrumb', ['$location', '$route', '$routeParams', function(location, route, routeParams) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             console.log(attrs.myValue); // the value on the directive
             // yourArray.push(attrs.myValue);

             scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(next, current) { 
                  var loc = location.path();
                  if(loc.indexOf('/users') >-1 && loc!='/users') 
                      scope.crumb= [{href:"/users",val:"Meine Kommilitonen"}, 
                        {href:"/users/"+current.params.id,val: current.params.id}];
             });
         },
         template: '<div ng-bind="test"></div><div style="float:left" ng-repeat="item in crumb"><a href="{{item.href}}">{{item.val}}</a></div><div style="clear:both"></div>'
    }
}])
```

Comment: No sorry i didn't mean that. I know how that works. I want to write s.th. like this: {href: '/users', val: {{users.name}}} where users is a val which is defined in the controller. but i dont want to define it because it should be short (just the directive, nothing more)